# asp.net mvc jquery load function and loading image?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-load

I have following code to load partialView :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customer_operations_container").load('/Customer/_AddCustomer');
}
```

Could I show a loading image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // show loading animation        
    $("#loading-animation").show();

    $("#customer_operations_container").load('/Customer/_AddCustomer', function() {
         // this function is the callback of the 'load' method
         // hide loading animation
         $("#loading-animation").hide();
    });
}
```